# Warning on redirecting https://www.example.net to https://example.com

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

Using Nginx and Let's Encrypt, I have a domain example.com which is secured by Let's Encrypt.

I have another domain name example.net which is redirected as bellow :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.net *.example.net;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
}
```

All the Uri's  `http://www.example.net` , `http://example.net`, `www.example.net`, `example.net` returns `https://example.com` and no problem.

When I type `https://www.example.net` or `https://example.net` the Warning on browser is :

> Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for example.net . The certificate is only valid for the following names: example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I need to know that should I add/get certificate for `example.net` in addition to my main domain `example.com` ?? So I need to, two certificates to resolve this problem or any other solution ?

Comment: You don’t need two certificates. When you try to fetch a new certificate for all the required domains, you will be asked if you would like to add the additional domains to the existing certificate.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But most of the people will panic, while exposing/seeing this warning and might leave the web page! I need no alert/warning

Comment: I assume that is an incomplete config or `listen 443;` would make no sense without references to the SSL files.

You don't need two certificates if you have subject alt names with the connect certs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup does not provide a valid certificate for this domain. To fix it, you have two options:

1. Replace the existing certificate with a certificate that covers `www.example.net`, `example.net`, `www.example.com` and `example.com`. Use the certificate in all virtual host blocks in your configuration.
2. Have two different certificate, one for `example.net` and `www.example.net` and second one for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. Then, add each certificate to corresponding virtual host block.